# How to add sub report in SSRS

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssrs-2008-r2, sql-server-data-tools

How can I add sub report with parameter in SSRS report using visual studio 2015.

I have tried a lot but getting this error  "A Value expression used for the report parameter ‘ID’ refers to a field.  Fields cannot be used in report parameter expressions."

Answer (score 0):

Where you are setting your Parameter for your subreport, you should have something like:

```
=Fields!CUSTNAME.Value
```

I'm guessing that what you actually have is something like this:

```
=Fields!CUSTNAME
```

So you're missing the ".Value".